# Android/iOS request web service with static method/singleton

Tags: android, ios

For iOS, I have written my web-service using AFNetworking like this. It is written in singleton class.

```
- (void)getNewsFeedWithView:(UIView *)view andPage:(NSInteger)page andNextRequestID:(NSInteger)nextRequestID andAutoDetectNewsfeedID:(NSInteger )autodetectNewsfeedID andSuccessBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionary *dict))successBlock andFailureBlock:(void (^)(NSError *error, NSString *responseString))failureBlock
{
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", SERVER_PREFIX, NEWSFEED_VERSION, NEWSFEED_DATA];
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] forKey:@"page"];//it needs to be always zero
    [parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:10] forKey:@"newsfeedNumber"];
    [parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:nextRequestID] forKey:@"nextRequestNewsfeedId"];
    [parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:autodetectNewsfeedID] forKey:@"autoDetectNewsfeedId"];


    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [WSHelper showHUD:view];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlStr parameters:parameters];
    [operation
     setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         [WSHelper hideHUD:HUD andView:view];
         if (successBlock) {
             successBlock(responseObject);
         }
     }

     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"Error: %@ \n %@", operation.responseString,[error description]);

         [WSHelper hideHUD:HUD andView:view];

         if (failureBlock)
             failureBlock(error, operation.responseString);
     }];

    [self.manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

For android, I have written my web-service using Fast Networking like this. This is not in singleton class and I just write static method.

```
   public static void getNewsfeed(int page, int nextRequestNewsfeedId, int autoDetectNewsfeedId, final Activity activity, final WSListener callback ) {

        final String errorMsg = "Fail to get Newsfeed";

        final KProgressHUD hud = showHUD(activity);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("page", page);
            obj.put("newsfeedNumber", "10");
            obj.put("nextRequestNewsfeedId", nextRequestNewsfeedId);
            obj.put("autoDetectNewsfeedId", autoDetectNewsfeedId);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String urlStr = SERVER_PREFIX + NEWSFEED_VERSION + NEWSFEED_DATA;
        AndroidNetworking.post(urlStr)
                .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                .addJSONObjectBody(obj) // posting json
                .addHeaders("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
                .addHeaders("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeaders("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
                .addHeaders("Authorization", getToken(activity))
                .build()
                .getAsOkHttpResponseAndJSONObject(new OkHttpResponseAndJSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response okHttpResponse, JSONObject response) {
                        callback.onResponse(response);
                        hideHUD(hud);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        callback.onError(anError.getErrorBody().toString(), activity);
                        hideHUD(hud);
                    }
                });
    }
```

I want to verify whether it is good to write like this.

1) Is my view kept in memory? What happen if my view is released from memory and calling web-service is in progress?

2) Is there any memory leak issue?

3) Is there any disadvantage? How can I write better method to call my web-services?

Comment: It's good to go like this.

Comment: For more better call, check the sample project https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture